# Textarea to support foreign languages

Tags: html, textarea

I have a textarea that works fine when I enter English in it but when I enter any other language, e.g. Urdu, Arabic, etc. some of the characters entered turned into boxes... and when the value is shown on other page... all the characters are shown as "?".

Is there any way to make textarea accept all languages?

Regards!

Comment: I think it's more of an app-locale issue. Or just use this: <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Language" content="EN">

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there could be a couple issues.

First is to make sure your charset is set to UTF-8.

Example:

Also, if you are submitting the values and storing them to be displayed on another page, you need to make sure that whatever mechanism  you are using to store the data (for example in a db), that your storage mechanism is also setup to support UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

First, check the font issues that @jetfire’s answer describes. But the basic problem seems to be a font issue. By default, browsers usually render `textarea` content in a monospace font. That’s questionable in many ways, and rather unsuitable for Arabic writing, so try setting e.g.

```
textarea { font-family: Cambria, serif; }
```